# Counting a recordset on an MS Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to make an if statement that returns an event depending if a recordset on a form is Greater than 0 (if records exist or not).  I am using the following code on the "on current" event on form "frmValueAddReporting01" but it is giving a syntax error message.

```
If Me.Form.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
   Me.Etichetta12.Visible = False
ElseIf Me.Form.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
   Me.Etichetta12.Visible = True

End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Although it is common to use `Forms!myFormName` to refer to a form in VBA code with `Forms` referring to the Collection of forms, in this case you have to address the form property of your form explicitly, i.e. `Form` comes after the name:

`Forms!frmValueAddReporting01.Form.Recordset.RecordCount`.

or leaving out the formname when addressed from the form's own module:

`Me.Form.Recordset.RecordCount`

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, a single line is fine, but it *is* needed. I've arrived here from a moderation queue because this was automatically flagged. Keeping answers to high quality will help prevent that.

Comment: @Veedrac you are, of course, right. I edited the answer.

Comment: I have edited the code above.  It is not working however on the "On current" event. It does work however on the "on load" event.  The form is a sub form embedded in a main form. It must have something to do with this.  Is there a different event which i should use?

Comment: The Form_Current event isn't fired on an empty set since there is no current record. You can put the code in the Form_Current event of the Main form however, since that record has to change for the correlated subform to change. If the subform is unbound and the recordset assigned by yourself (per code), you should put the code after the assignment of the recordsource.